# CodeIgniter Session is not destroying

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem with my session. It's not destroying. And when I go back to previous page, the session is still there.

Please have a look at my codes:

**user_model.php - model**

```
   <?php
 class User_Model extends CI_Model
 {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function login($username, $password)
{
    $this->db->where("username", $username);
    $this->db->where("password", $password);

    $query=$this->db->get("users");
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                    //'user_id'         => $rows->id,
                    'username' => $rows->username,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
               ); 

        }
            $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
            return true;            
    }
    return false;
}

public function add_user()
{
    $data=array(
        'username'=> $this->input->post('username'),
        'password'=> $this->input->post('password')// md5($this->input->post('password'))
        );
    $this->db->insert('users',$data);
}
   }
   ?>
```

**user.php - controller**

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class User extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
}
public function index()
{
    if(($this->session->userdata('username') != "" ))
    {
        $this->welcome();
    }
    else {
        $data['title']= 'Home';
        $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
        $this->load->view("frontpage", $data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
    }
}
public function welcome()
{
    $data['title']= 'Welcome';
    $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/navbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('welcome_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/sidebar', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/ftr', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer', $data);
}
public function login()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password'); // md5($this->input->post('password'));

    $result = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);

    if($result) 
        $this->welcome();
    else       
        $this->index();

}
public function thank()
{
    $data['title']= 'Thank';
    $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('thank_view.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
}
public function registration()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    // field name, error message, validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('con_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->user_model->add_user();
        $this->thank();
    }
}
public function logout()
{
    $newdata = array(
    //'user_id'   =>'',
    'username'  => '',
    'logged_in' => FALSE
    );

    $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata);
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->index();
}
 }
 ?>
```

I don't know what's wrong with these codes. Can anybody point to me what's wrong? I really need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store sessions into database. Read CodeIgniter documentation to know how to perform this. I had the same problem and sessions table was a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to end of **config.php** file  to prevent page caching issue,

```
function __autoload($class)
{
 header("cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
 header("cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
}
```